# Quais os tipos de encriptações javascript?

Tags: javascript, hexadecimal

Estava fuçando alguns códigos pela net e vi que alguns scripts estavam encriptados.

Eu não consegui fazer o decode da forma correta pelo HexDecoder, pois provavelmente há mais de um tipo de encriptação no código.

```js
var _0x4a00=["\x31\x64\x28\x72\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x31\x28\x24\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x22\x71\x2E\x31\x46\x2D\x39\x22\x29\x2E\x31\x66\x28\x22\x31\x75\x22\x29\x2E\x31\x45\x28\x22\x39\x2D\x58\x2D\x4B\x2D\x4F\x22\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x36\x2D\x32\x20\x2E\x39\x2D\x58\x2D\x4B\x2D\x4F\x20\x3E\x20\x61\x27\x29\x2E\x78\x28\x27\x3C\x38\x20\x62\x3D\x22\x31\x7A\x2D\x31\x43\x22\x3E\x20\x3C\x69\x20\x62\x3D\x22\x6B\x20\x6B\x2D\x31\x48\x2D\x31\x4A\x22\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x38\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x36\x2D\x32\x20\x2E\x31\x51\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x53\x28\x27\x3C\x6D\x20\x31\x65\x3D\x22\x39\x2D\x45\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x20\x62\x3D\x22\x6B\x20\x6B\x2D\x31\x68\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6D\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x39\x2D\x45\x27\x29\x2E\x59\x28\x27\x70\x27\x2C\x31\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x36\x2D\x32\x20\x71\x27\x29\x2E\x4D\x28\x4E\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x67\x29\x2E\x31\x47\x28\x31\x28\x29\x7B\x68\x20\x77\x3D\x24\x28\x67\x29\x2E\x31\x50\x28\x29\x3B\x68\x20\x76\x3D\x24\x28\x27\x23\x36\x2D\x32\x20\x71\x27\x29\x3B\x64\x28\x77\x3E\x31\x54\x26\x26\x76\x2E\x31\x37\x28\x27\x3A\x31\x62\x27\x29\x29\x7B\x76\x2E\x31\x63\x28\x27\x79\x27\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x4C\x2D\x45\x27\x29\x2E\x59\x28\x27\x70\x27\x2C\x31\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x32\x2D\x4C\x27\x29\x2E\x4D\x28\x4E\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x68\x20\x24\x6F\x3D\x24\x28\x27\x23\x36\x2D\x32\x20\x23\x73\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x6A\x28\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x36\x2D\x32\x20\x23\x73\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x6B\x28\x31\x28\x29\x7B\x64\x28\x37\x2E\x66\x2E\x31\x41\x3D\x3D\x3D\x30\x29\x7B\x37\x2E\x66\x3D\x24\x6F\x7D\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x36\x2D\x32\x20\x23\x73\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x44\x28\x31\x28\x29\x7B\x64\x28\x37\x2E\x66\x3D\x3D\x3D\x24\x6F\x29\x7B\x37\x2E\x66\x3D\x27\x27\x7D\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x46\x2D\x54\x20\x2E\x34\x20\x57\x27\x29\x2E\x52\x28\x22\x3C\x6D\x20\x62\x3D\x27\x34\x2D\x33\x27\x2F\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x46\x2D\x54\x20\x2E\x34\x2D\x33\x27\x29\x2E\x78\x28\x22\x3C\x38\x3E\x3C\x2F\x38\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x22\x2E\x47\x2D\x34\x20\x2E\x34\x20\x57\x22\x29\x2E\x52\x28\x22\x3C\x6D\x20\x62\x3D\x27\x34\x2D\x33\x27\x2F\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x47\x2D\x34\x20\x2E\x34\x2D\x33\x27\x29\x2E\x78\x28\x22\x3C\x38\x3E\x3C\x2F\x38\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x22\x2E\x31\x52\x20\x2E\x48\x2D\x49\x2C\x2E\x31\x55\x20\x2E\x48\x2D\x49\x22\x29\x2E\x31\x57\x28\x31\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x37\x29\x2E\x4A\x28\x22\x2E\x31\x38\x2D\x31\x39\x20\x2E\x31\x61\x20\x61\x22\x29\x2E\x75\x28\x22\x79\x22\x2C\x31\x28\x65\x2C\x74\x29\x7B\x6C\x20\x74\x2E\x7A\x28\x22\x2F\x31\x67\x2E\x50\x22\x2C\x22\x2F\x31\x69\x2E\x50\x22\x29\x7D\x29\x2E\x75\x28\x22\x79\x22\x2C\x31\x28\x65\x2C\x74\x29\x7B\x6C\x20\x74\x2E\x7A\x28\x22\x51\x2D\x63\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x6C\x22\x29\x7D\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x37\x29\x2E\x4A\x28\x22\x2E\x31\x6D\x20\x31\x6E\x22\x29\x2E\x75\x28\x22\x31\x6F\x22\x2C\x31\x28\x65\x2C\x74\x29\x7B\x6C\x20\x74\x2E\x7A\x28\x22\x51\x2D\x63\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x70\x2D\x63\x22\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x31\x71\x2D\x31\x72\x2D\x31\x73\x27\x29\x2E\x70\x28\x31\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x31\x74\x2C\x35\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x76\x28\x7B\x31\x77\x3A\x30\x7D\x2C\x31\x78\x29\x3B\x6C\x20\x31\x79\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x61\x5B\x42\x3D\x22\x43\x2D\x31\x42\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x44\x28\x24\x28\x27\x23\x43\x2D\x55\x27\x29\x2E\x35\x28\x29\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x43\x2D\x55\x27\x29\x2E\x35\x28\x27\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x61\x5B\x42\x3D\x22\x56\x2D\x33\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x44\x28\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x6E\x2D\x33\x2D\x6A\x27\x29\x2E\x35\x28\x29\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x6E\x2D\x33\x2D\x6A\x27\x29\x2E\x35\x28\x27\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x61\x5B\x42\x3D\x22\x56\x2D\x41\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x44\x28\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x6E\x2D\x41\x2D\x6A\x27\x29\x2E\x35\x28\x29\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x6E\x2D\x41\x2D\x6A\x27\x29\x2E\x35\x28\x27\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x72\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x31\x28\x65\x29\x7B\x65\x28\x22\x31\x49\x2E\x5A\x22\x29\x2E\x5A\x28\x29\x7D\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x67\x2E\x31\x4B\x3D\x31\x28\x29\x7B\x68\x20\x65\x3D\x72\x2E\x31\x4C\x28\x22\x31\x4D\x22\x29\x3B\x64\x28\x65\x3D\x3D\x31\x4E\x29\x7B\x67\x2E\x31\x4F\x2E\x31\x30\x3D\x22\x31\x31\x3A\x2F\x2F\x31\x32\x2E\x31\x33\x2E\x31\x34\x2F\x22\x7D\x65\x2E\x31\x35\x28\x22\x31\x30\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x31\x3A\x2F\x2F\x31\x32\x2E\x31\x33\x2E\x31\x34\x2F\x22\x29\x3B\x65\x2E\x31\x35\x28\x22\x33\x22\x2C\x22\x20\x31\x56\x20\x31\x36\x22\x29\x3B\x65\x2E\x31\x58\x3D\x22\x31\x59\x20\x31\x36\x22\x7D","\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x6E\x61\x76\x7C\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x77\x69\x64\x67\x65\x74\x7C\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x7C\x6D\x61\x69\x6E\x7C\x74\x68\x69\x73\x7C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x7C\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x7C\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x7C\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x7C\x62\x6F\x78\x7C\x66\x61\x7C\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x7C\x64\x69\x76\x7C\x61\x64\x73\x7C\x6E\x61\x76\x46\x6F\x72\x6D\x56\x61\x6C\x75\x65\x7C\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x7C\x75\x6C\x7C\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x7C\x7C\x61\x74\x74\x72\x7C\x6E\x61\x76\x44\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x7C\x7C\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x7C\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x7C\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x7C\x69\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x7C\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x61\x75\x74\x68\x6F\x72\x7C\x62\x65\x66\x6F\x72\x65\x7C\x69\x63\x6F\x6E\x7C\x73\x69\x64\x65\x62\x61\x72\x7C\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x7C\x6F\x75\x74\x65\x72\x7C\x66\x69\x6E\x64\x7C\x68\x61\x73\x7C\x73\x65\x61\x72\x63\x68\x7C\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65\x7C\x32\x35\x30\x7C\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E\x7C\x6A\x70\x67\x7C\x73\x37\x32\x7C\x77\x72\x61\x70\x7C\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x7C\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x68\x65\x61\x64\x7C\x61\x64\x7C\x68\x32\x7C\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x7C\x6F\x6E\x7C\x74\x69\x6D\x65\x61\x67\x6F\x7C\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x68\x74\x74\x70\x7C\x77\x77\x77\x7C\x73\x6F\x72\x61\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x7C\x54\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x69\x73\x7C\x62\x6C\x6F\x63\x6B\x7C\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x7C\x68\x69\x64\x64\x65\x6E\x7C\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x41\x74\x74\x72\x7C\x6A\x51\x75\x65\x72\x79\x7C\x69\x64\x7C\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x7C\x6E\x61\x76\x69\x63\x6F\x6E\x7C\x6D\x71\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x7C\x76\x61\x6C\x7C\x62\x6C\x75\x72\x7C\x73\x31\x30\x30\x30\x7C\x50\x6F\x70\x75\x6C\x61\x72\x50\x6F\x73\x74\x73\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x73\x39\x30\x7C\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x7C\x74\x6F\x7C\x74\x6F\x70\x7C\x62\x6F\x64\x79\x7C\x6C\x69\x7C\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x54\x6F\x70\x7C\x38\x30\x30\x7C\x66\x61\x6C\x73\x65\x7C\x64\x72\x6F\x70\x7C\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7C\x70\x75\x73\x68\x7C\x73\x69\x67\x6E\x7C\x66\x6F\x63\x75\x73\x7C\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x73\x75\x62\x7C\x72\x65\x73\x69\x7A\x65\x7C\x63\x61\x72\x65\x74\x7C\x61\x62\x62\x72\x7C\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x7C\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64\x7C\x6D\x79\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x6E\x75\x6C\x6C\x7C\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x7C\x72\x6F\x77\x7C\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x7C\x70\x72\x65\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x7C\x31\x30\x31\x30\x7C\x61\x72\x63\x68\x69\x76\x65\x7C\x42\x6C\x6F\x67\x67\x65\x72\x7C\x65\x61\x63\x68\x7C\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x7C\x53\x6F\x72\x61","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];eval(function(_0xd77bx1,_0xd77bx2,_0xd77bx3,_0xd77bx4,_0xd77bx5,_0xd77bx6){_0xd77bx5=function(_0xd77bx3){return (_0xd77bx3<_0xd77bx2?_0x4a00[4]:_0xd77bx5(parseInt(_0xd77bx3/_0xd77bx2)))+((_0xd77bx3=_0xd77bx3%_0xd77bx2)>35?String[_0x4a00[5]](_0xd77bx3+29):_0xd77bx3.toString(36))};if(!_0x4a00[4][_0x4a00[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0xd77bx3--){_0xd77bx6[_0xd77bx5(_0xd77bx3)]=_0xd77bx4[_0xd77bx3]||_0xd77bx5(_0xd77bx3)};_0xd77bx4=[function(_0xd77bx5){return _0xd77bx6[_0xd77bx5]}];_0xd77bx5=function(){return _0x4a00[7]};_0xd77bx3=1;};while(_0xd77bx3--){if(_0xd77bx4[_0xd77bx3]){_0xd77bx1=_0xd77bx1[_0x4a00[6]]( new RegExp(_0x4a00[8]+_0xd77bx5(_0xd77bx3)+_0x4a00[8],_0x4a00[9]),_0xd77bx4[_0xd77bx3])}};return _0xd77bx1;}(_0x4a00[0],62,123,_0x4a00[3][_0x4a00[2]](_0x4a00[1]),0,{}));
```

Qual seria o processo de desencriptação e quais os tipos de encriptação javascript?

Por exemplo, o Hex é nesse formato: `\x31` o outro (que não faço ideia qual seja) é nesse `_0xd77bx3` e assim por diante.

Comment: Isso não é encriptação, é uma mera troca de caracteres só pra espantar curioso. Nada do lado do cliente tem como ser de fato ocultado. Se o _browser_ interpreta, o usuário tem como fazer o mesmo.

Comment: @Bacco Então encriptação javascript não existe?

Comment: Existem funções que podem ajudar em encriptação, como o Mega faz para sincronizar arquivos, mas isso com ajuda do lado do servidor, e para baixar dados. O que não dá é para encriptar código JS de maneira ao usuário final não ler. Para o _browser_ rodar um JS, ele tem que reverter a ocultação do código, senão não tem o que rodar.

Comment: Isso é claro, pois ele trabalha do lado do cliente. Mas não seria considerado um tipo de encriptação, por mais "pobre" que seja?

Comment: Do ponto de vista do "dicionário", até Cifra de César é uma forma de "criptografia". Do ponto de vista da segurança da informação, é outra coisa, uma mera troca de símbolos não passa nem perto de algo considerado criptográfico.

Comment: Se tiver a curiosidade, veja o código acima "descriptografado": Só troquei o `eval` por `document.write`, mais nada: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyxogz - como comentei, é só pra espantar curioso mesmo.

Comment: E sabe quais formas ele utilizou para "esconder" o código? Vi que tem algo em hexadecimal ali xD

Comment: provavelmente algum script pronto pra isso, talvez até online. Basicamente troca parte dos caracteres por hexa, divide partes dos dados em uma função que gera a string original, e roda com eval. Trocando o eval por document.write desfazemos em segundos o que a pessoa gastou alguns minutos pra fazer. Mas de qualquer forma, mesmo que a técnica seja completamente diferente dessa, vai cair sempre no mesmo. Desfazer é mais rápido que fazer, e qualquer pessoa com conhecimento do básico de JS sabe disso, então não vale muito o esforço.